# "as" followed by a adjective

Tags: grammar

In the sentences like these:

> I thought of my new watch as crippled.
>
> The girls perceived the school as decisive.
>
> I thought of this as damaged.

Word "as" is followed by adjectives. I knew that it is possible, but I am more familiar with the "as" followed by nouns like "I thought of my new watch as a crippled watch." What makes it possible? Is there a official rule that enables me to do this? Or is ellipsis used?

Comment: English has no "official rules", as some languages do (Icelandic, perhaps, or French), and most types of ellipsis are patterns as well-established as anything else. That doesn't specifically answer your question, but it's a misconception that's useful to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Using "as" in that way is the same as if you were saying "as being."  You thought of your new watch *as being* crippled; you thought of this *as being* damaged.  You don't need to have the word "being" there (although you could, if you wished); it is implied.  You do not need an ellipsis.  In your example regarding the decisive school, however, there's a problem: a school cannot be decisive.  In trying to imagine the intended meaning, I thought perhaps something like "The girls perceived the school as overcrowded, a decisive factor in their rejection of it," but I'm just guessing there.  I hope this helps.